# Как в переменную окружения добавить путь из которой я запускаю программу?

Tags: node.js

Я пишу свой менеджер пакетов (эксперимент) на nodeJS. Как мне добавить в переменную окружения node текущую директорию из которой я запускаю программу (программа добавленна в path windows и запускается из любой папки — node menejer.js)? Не путь к директории в которой находиться сам менеджер! А директория из которой я запускаю менеджер!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы узнать, из какой директории был запущен процесс **nodejs**, можно использовать команду

```
process.cwd()
```

Для того, что бы значение положить в переменную окружения, необходимо присвоить это значение в **process.env**

```
process.env.runDir = process.cwd();

console.log(process.env.runDir)
```